# How to calculate sunrise and sunset in Julia

Tags: julia

Python has `suntime`, R has `suntimes` - is there a similar package to work with sunrise/set in Julia? I've looked on [https://juliahub.com](https://juliahub.com/ui/Search?q=Sun&type=packages) but can't find anything. How to calculate the time of sunset at a given location and date in Julia? Similar to this in Python:

```
from suntime import Sun

sun = Sun(LAT, LON)

today_ss = sun.get_local_sunset_time()
```

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be a pure Julia package dedicated to this. Short of reimplementing one of these in Julia (probably not too hard —- could be the one to make this!), you could use PyCall.jl or RCall.jl to use the python or r packages you mention, respectively, from Julia.